# Help on Regular Expression problem

Tags: python, regex, unicode, string

i wonder if it's possible to make a RegEx for the following data pattern:

'152: Ashkenazi A, Benlifer A, Korenblit J, Silberstein SD.'

```
string = '152: Ashkenazi A, Benlifer A, Korenblit J, Silberstein SD.'
```

I am using this Regular Expression (Using Python's re module) to extract these names:

```
re.findall(r'(\d+): (.+), (.+), (.+), (.+).', string, re.M | re.S)
```

Result:

```
[('152', 'Ashkenazi A', 'Benlifer A', 'Korenblit J', 'Silberstein SD')]
```

Now trying with a different number (less than 4 or more than 4) of name data pattern doesn't work anymore because the RegEx expects to find only 4 of them:

```
(.+), (.+), (.+), (.+).
```

I can't find a way to generalize this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick if you only want the stuff after the numbers:

```
re.findall(r'\d+: (.+)(?:, .+)*\.', input, re.M | re.S)
```

And if you want everything:

```
re.findall(r'(\d+): (.+)(?:, .+)*\.', input, re.M | re.S)
```

And if you want to get them separated out into a list of matches, a nested regex will do it:

```
re.findall(r'[^,]+,|[^,]+$', re.findall(r'\d+: (.+)(?:, .+)*\.', input, re.M | re.S)[0],re.M|re.S)
```

Comment: Odd. The same regex is working for me. That said, after looking back at his input the final `.` should probably be a literal `\.`

Comment: Ah, with another look I see what you mean (I think). I've edited so that the extraneous other junk isn't included (unless he wants it).

Comment: It works but i still need to split the names with a ".split(',')".

Comment: Another option added: this one returns the individual matches.

Comment: My result is ['Ashkenazi A,', ' Benlifer A,', ' Korenblit J,', ''], one name is missing from the list.

Comment: Ok, I'm off at dinner. Will perfect it to match exactly when I get home. I think I can get rid of the blank match too.

Comment: There we go. As I thought, the latest edit is returning everything exactly as desired.

Answer (score 6):

A regular expression probably isn't the best way to solve this. You could use [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.split):

```
>>> s = '152: Ashkenazi A, Benlifer A, Korenblit J, Silberstein SD.'
>>> s.split(": ")
['152', 'Ashkenazi A, Benlifer A, Korenblit J, Silberstein SD.']
>>> s.split(": ")[1].split(", ")
['Ashkenazi A', 'Benlifer A', 'Korenblit J', 'Silberstein SD.']
```

Comment: I am considering to mark this one as the solution to my problem, but i'll wait to see if someone else can provide a pure RegEx solution to my question. Just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

If you means that there may be more (or less too) names, you should maybe try something like this:
`(\d+): (.+)*`? Asterisk (*) means 0 or more occurrence of (.+)

Answer (score 0):

I can get close, but further processing may be necessary.  It is probably better to do manual string splitting, especially if the data is reliably well-formatted.

### Code

```
import re
string1 = '152: Ashkenazi A, Benlifer A, Korenblit J, Silberstein SD.'
string2 = '152: Ashkenazi A, Benlifer A, Korenblit J, Silberstein SD, Hattingh CJR.'
for i in [string1, string2]:
    print re.findall(r'(\d+):|(?:[.,\s?])?(.*?)(?:[.,])', i)
```

### Output

```
[('152', ''), ('', 'Ashkenazi A'), ('', 'Benlifer A'), ('', 'Korenblit J'), ('', 'Silberstein SD')]
[('152', ''), ('', 'Ashkenazi A'), ('', 'Benlifer A'), ('', 'Korenblit J'), ('', 'Silberstein SD'), ('', 'Hattingh CJR')]
```

### Edit: using 2 expressions

If you are willing to use two regex expressions, it can be done fairly painlessly:

```
import re
string1 = '152: Ashkenazi A, Benlifer A, Korenblit J, Silberstein SD.'
string2 = '152: Ashkenazi A, Benlifer A, Korenblit J, Silberstein SD, Hattingh CJR.'
for i in [string1, string2]:
    print re.findall(r'^(\d+):', i)
    print re.findall(r'(?:[:,] )(\S+ [A-Z]+)(?=[\.,])', i)
```

produces

```
['152']
['Ashkenazi A', 'Benlifer A', 'Korenblit J', 'Silberstein SD']
['152']
['Ashkenazi A', 'Benlifer A', 'Korenblit J', 'Silberstein SD', 'Hattingh CJR']
```

Comment: Well you got near indeed :) i can barely read that regular expression!

Comment: Nice solution! :) It is similiar to @JGB146 's as it requires more than one regex. Thanks!